# How can I override the field in my view?

Tags: views, 8

I have a view for a content type with a number of fields. For one of the fields (List, text) (node_field_type) I would like to override the output result. It can be either type_1 or type_2 . In the database the type is stored in node_field_type table in field_type_value column.

So in the settings of the field under "Rewrite results" tab I picked "Override the output of this field with custom text"

```
<span class="tag-{{ field_node_type|lower }}"></span>
```

But it doesnt assign any class to html tag.
Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the field `field_node_type` called somewhere in your view to use it as a token in rewrite results for a field. Value that you're trying to use in rewrite results should be available within replacement patterns for the field you're trying to configure.

[image]